# 'unexport' in Makefile fails to work

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion), we have:

> If you want to *prevent* a variable from being exported, use the
>   'unexport' directive, like this:
>
> unexport VARIABLE ...

But, in practice, however, given a makefile:

```
unexport foo

all:
    @$(MAKE) recursive

recursive:
    @echo $(foo)
```

And running:

```
$ make foo=bar
```

We get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/myname'
bar
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/myname'
```

Which looks like the variable `foo` had indeed been exported, despite the explicit directive above `unexport foo`. Why?

Comment: What happens if you run `foo=bar make` instead of `make foo=bar`?

Comment: And what version of Make are you using? (If in doubt, try `make -v`)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the documentation also says:

> `make` automatically passes down variable values that were defined on the command line, by putting them in the `MAKEFLAGS` variable.

When you run:

```
make foo=bar
```

the variables are passed down.  If you run:

```
foo=bar make
```

the shell exports the variable, and the `unexport` in the `makefile` prevents it being exported to the submake.

---

I already had a `makefile`, so I called this one `xx.mk`, and augmented it as follows:

```
unexport foo

all:
    @echo "MAKEFLAGS=${MAKEFLAGS}"
    @$(MAKE) -f xx.mk recursive

recursive:
    @echo "MAKEFLAGS=${MAKEFLAGS}"
    @echo $(foo)
```

When run, I got:

```
$ foo=bar make -f xx.mk 
MAKEFLAGS=
MAKEFLAGS=

$ make -f xx.mk foo=bar
MAKEFLAGS=foo=bar
MAKEFLAGS=foo=bar
bar
$
```